# Show all items in owl carousel 2 or prev version

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

[DEMO Owl Carousel 2](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/H4wzr/)

[Owl Carousel 2 website](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)

I need to add button "view all" but how it's made?

for now it's just a carousel code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    items: 9,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

UPDATED: [**FINISHED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/H4wzr/)

---

**JS:**

```
$(".owl-show-all").click(function () {
    $("#owl-example").toggleClass("show_all");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.show_all .owl-stage {
    width:980px !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0px) !important;
}
.owl-stage {
    transition: 0.7s !important;
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s !important;
}
.owl-item.cloned {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/H4wzr/2/)**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    items: 9,
});
$(".owl-nav").append('<div class="owl-show-all" style="">Show All</div>');

$("body").on("click",".owl-show-all",function(){
 alert('here comes yout show all logic');
});
```